# How to extend shading in this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

The following figure is meant to be a contour graph. How can I extend the current shading out to the rest of the figure, so that there is shading between all of the lines?

Here is the the figure and the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcounter{cntShader}
  \setcounter{cntShader}{60}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (+80:4) coordinate (b);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (-80:4) coordinate (c);
  \draw (o) -- (+170:3);
  \draw (o) -- (-170:3);
  \foreach \rad in {3,2.5,...,.5} {
    \draw pic[draw,fill=gray!\thecntShader, angle radius=\rad cm] {angle=c--o--b};
    \pgfmathsetcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader-10}
    \setcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader}
    \draw (+80:\rad cm) -- +(+170:3cm);
    \draw (-80:\rad cm) -- +(-170:3cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does it (but is not the simplest way to obtain the result).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcounter{cntShader}
  \setcounter{cntShader}{60}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (+80:4) coordinate (b);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (-80:4) coordinate (c);
  \draw (o) -- (+170:3);
  \draw (o) -- (-170:3);
  \foreach \rad in {3,2.5,...,.5} {
    \draw pic[draw,fill=gray!\thecntShader, angle radius=\rad cm] {angle=c--o--b};
    \path (+80:\rad cm-0.5cm) +(+170:3cm) coordinate (auxp)
    (-80:\rad cm-0.5cm) +(-170:3cm) coordinate (auxm);
    \path[fill=gray!\thecntShader] (+80:\rad cm) -- +(+170:3cm) -- (auxp)
     -- (+80:\rad cm-0.5cm) -- cycle;
    \path[fill=gray!\thecntShader] (-80:\rad cm) -- +(-170:3cm) -- (auxm)
     -- (-80:\rad cm-0.5cm) -- cycle;
    \pgfmathsetcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader-10}
    \setcounter{cntShader}{\thecntShader}
    \draw (+80:\rad cm) -- +(+170:3cm);
    \draw (-80:\rad cm) -- +(-170:3cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would go along an arguably easier path:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \foreach \rad [count=\Z starting from 0] in {3,2.5,...,.5}  {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\GL}{60-10*\Z}
  \draw[line width=5mm,gray!\GL] (+80:\rad cm-0.25cm) +(+170:3cm) -- (+80:\rad cm-0.25cm)
  arc(80:-80:\rad cm-0.25cm) -- ++ (-170:3cm);
  \draw (+80:\rad cm) +(+170:3cm) -- (+80:\rad cm)
  arc(80:-80:\rad cm) -- ++ (-170:3cm);}
  \draw (+170:3cm) -- (o) -- (-170:3cm);
  \draw[<->] (+80:4) coordinate (b) -- (o) -- (-80:4) coordinate (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 More efficient as always:)

Comment: Thanks for the code! This looks great. It's easier to tell with the PDF: the vertex of the narrow cone (which opens to the left), protrudes just to the right of the origin, where it intersects with the lines that lean at 80 and -80 degrees. Is there a way of eliminating this?

Comment: @Michael Yes, of course. Just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcounter{cntShader}
  \setcounter{cntShader}{60}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (+80:4) coordinate (b);
  \draw[->] (o) -- (-80:4) coordinate (c);
  \draw (o) -- (+170:3);
  \draw (o) -- (-170:3);
  \foreach \rad [evaluate=\rad as \prad using {\rad-0.5}, count=\c,
                 evaluate=\c as \sh using {70-10*\c}] in {3,2.5,...,.5} {
    \draw pic[draw,fill=gray!\sh, angle radius=\rad cm] {angle=c--o--b};
    \draw[fill=gray!\sh](+80:\prad cm)--(+80:\rad cm)--++(170:3cm)--($(+80:\prad cm)+(170:3cm)$)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=gray!\sh](-80:\prad cm)--(-80:\rad cm)--++(-170:3cm)--($(-80:\prad cm)+(-170:3cm)$)--cycle;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note also that I have replaced your `cntShader` with `\sh` using `count=\c,
evaluate=\c as \sh using {70-10*\c}` inthe `\foreach` statement.